# Trouble Importing Lahman Baseball DB into MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm a new user to MySQL and MySQL workbench 8.0, and I am attempting to run the SQL script to open either the Lahman baseball database 2021 SQL version or the version from the Boston University Sabermetrics 101 course. Link below: https://github.com/WebucatorTraining/lahman-baseball-mysql

I tried following the instruction listed on the page: "To create the MySQL database and populate it, download updated-lahman-mysql.sql and import it into MySQL using Workbench:

1. Server > Data Import
2. Select Import from Self-Contained File
3. Pick any Default Target Schema. It will be ignored, as the file creates a new one.
4. Click Start Import button."

When trying these, MySQL Workbench returns with a message "Dump file not found; doesn't exist".

I tried the steps I mentioned above and I expected that after importing the data, I would be able to run queries in the workbench.

If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming error, you either did not select a file to be imported or workbench cannot find the file. Make sure you download the file to your local computer before trying to open it.

Comment: My apologies, I thought that the file would import from the self-contained file automatically given the instructions. I have now imported the entire zip file and this error message returned: 

"ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'PK'."

I'm not sure where to change this binary issue.